# C program segfault error

Tags: c

I want the output to be XOllo, but segfault is what I am getting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  char *buf="hello";
  char *xys="XO";

  while(*buf != 'l'){
  *buf = *xys;
  xys++;
  buf++;
  }
  printf("%s \n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

o/p-:
segfault

I need the o/p as XOllo, but I get seg fault. Please suggest.

```
Please suggest.
```

Comment: A string literal shouldn't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Variables `buf` and `xys` pointing to the string literals, which cannot not be changed, therefore trying to access to re-write the values leading to SIGFAULT, instead you need to allocate new variable and copy values into it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  char *buf="hello";
  char *xys="XO";
  char *tmp = (char *)malloc(strlen(buf));

  strcpy(tmp, xys);
  strcpy(tmp+2, buf+2);

  printf("%s \n", tmp);
  free(tmp);
  return 0;
}
```

If you need to find exact position of `l` character, you can use `strchr` function to get the index of it in the following way:

```
int index = -1
const char *ptr = strchr(buff, 'l');
if(ptr) {
   index = ptr - values;
}
```

Comment: I just want to point out that you have added a new header `stdlib.h` and OP might miss that. At the same time you have casted the result of `malloc`. That might hide the warning she would get if she missed the header and the results could be disastrous..

Comment: yes, you are correct, thanks for commenting.

Comment: No, the requirement is not to use library function .

Comment: Thanks Artem , in the new code, i can edit the string buf but not the same in previous case

Comment: could you probably open a new question, since now it seems to be completely different problem, moreover additional requirements of no new libs :)?

Comment: problem solved.close it.

Comment: you very welcome